# why selected value of combo box does not work

Tags: c#

I wrote below code, but it does not work correctly. As you see, I defined `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`. But it does not show `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` for all items, either I select `Selectable` item or not.

```
private class ComboBoxItem
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Selectable { get; set; }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this._cmb.ValueMember = "Value";
    this._cmb.DisplayMember = "Text";
    this._cmb.Items.AddRange(new[] {
        new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = false, Text="Unselectable", Value=0},
        new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable1", Value=1},
        new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable2", Value=2},
    });

    this._cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += (cbSender, cbe) =>
    {
        var cb = cbSender as ComboBox;

        if (cb.SelectedItem != null && cb.SelectedItem is ComboBoxItem && ((ComboBoxItem)cb.SelectedItem).Selectable == false)
        {
            // deselect item
            cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label.Text = _cmb.SelectedItem.ToString();  // it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        label.Text = _cmb.SelectedText.ToString();    // it returns ""
        label.Text = _cmb.SelectedValue.ToString();  // it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you must call DataBind

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a `NullRefernceException` when using the `SelectedItem` then that means no item is selected.  Make sure an item is selected and both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` will work.  `SelectedText` is not what you think though.  It works like the property with the same name on a `TextBox`.  You just want `Text`, not `SelectedText`.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why the `NullReferenceException` happened to you for the `selectedItem`, but the following code will work. And the SelectedValue will be null for some reason, so I just cast the `SelectedItem` back to `ComboBoxItem` type, then all its properties are accessible

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //label.Text = _cmb.SelectedItem.ToString();  // it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        //label.Text += _cmb.SelectedText.ToString();   // it returns ""
        //label.Text += _cmb.SelectedValue.ToString();  // it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem) this._cmb.SelectedItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            label.Text = item.Value.ToString();
            label.Text += item.Text;
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._cmb.ValueMember = "Value";
        this._cmb.DisplayMember = "Text";
        this._cmb.Items.AddRange(new[] {
            new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = false, Text="Unselectable", Value=0},
            new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable1", Value=1},
            new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable2", Value=2},
        });
        this._cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += (cbSender, cbe) =>
        {
            var cb = cbSender as ComboBox;

            if (cb.SelectedItem != null && cb.SelectedItem is ComboBoxItem && ((ComboBoxItem)cb.SelectedItem).Selectable == false)
            {
                // deselect item
                cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
        };
    }
}

public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Selectable { get; set; }
}
```

}